# How to create and object dynamically from given attributes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, excel, import

I have an excel files importer. I want to import records from excel sheets, which have column names with attributes names.

```
class DDImporter
  def initialize(path)
    @path = path 
  end

  def extract sheet_name
    file = Roo::Excelx.new(@path)
    file.default_sheet = sheet_name

    header = file.row 1
    2.upto(file.last_row) do |i|
      row = Hash[[header, file.row(i)].transpose]
      row.delete "id"
      # row => ['name', 'price', 'product_id']
      sheet_name.classify.constantize.where(name: row['name']).first_or_create # I need to put attributes hash here
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, I think you could use a `Struct` to achieve what you are looking for.

```
self.class.const_set(sheet_name.classify, Struct.new(*header.map(&:to_sym)))
```

Will create a class named `sheet_name` w/ accessors defined for all of the header values. So assuming a `sheet_name` of `foo`, you could do:

```
Foo.new(*row)
```

So all together:

```
header =  ['name', 'price', 'product_id']
row = ['blah', 123, 234]
sheet_name = 'foo'
Object.const_set(sheet_name.classify, Struct.new(*header.map(&:to_sym))) #=> Foo
Foo.new(*row) #=> #<struct Foo name="blah", price=123, product_id=234>
```

Note that b/c `self.class` is used above, this object will be namespaced under its parent. You could always call it on `Object` if that is not what you want